# What happens when there are two classes, one decorator/ one class two decorators in a file in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-cmp',
   template: '<div>Hello World!</div>'
}) // here component metadata

export class MyComponent {

}
```

So, the above is my actual component file. If I have another class

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-cmp',
   template: '<div>Hello World!</div>'
}) // here component metadata

export class MyComponent {

}

export class MyAnotherComponent {

}
```

and

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-cmp',
   template: '<div>Hello World!</div>'
}) // here component metadata
@Component({
   selector: 'my-cmpnt',
   template: '<div>Hello Something!</div>'
}) // here component metadata

export class MyComponent {

}
```

Now, Do I get any error? What happens?

Comment: Why would you like to do something like this when the first rule of style guide is to apply the single responsibility principle? https://angular.io/styleguide#!#single-responsibility

Comment: I just had a doubt that what happens if I mention like that

Comment: @Mr_Perfect, so does my answer sufficiently explain that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Two classes and one decorator

The `@Component` decorator is applied to the class that immediately follows the decorator. So in your case it's applied to `MyComponent`. Now, it also matters which class your specify in a module declarations. If you specify `MyComponent` - everything should be fine. If you specify `MyAnotherComponent` - you will get an error:

> Unexpected value ‘MyAnotherComponent’ declared by the module ‘AppModule’.
>   Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

because Angular will complain that this class is not an instance of a component because the decorator wasn't applied to it.

You can read more about `@Component` decorator and how it works [here](https://hackernoon.com/implementing-custom-component-decorator-in-angular-4d037d5a3f0d).

#### Two decorators and one class

In short, only the first decorator is used.

If you use two decorators on the same class, both will be applied to the class and store metadata on that class *in reverse order*, so that the first decorator properties stored in the last index. When the compiler resolves metadata it takes the last metadata properties using the [findLast](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.2.0-rc.1/packages/compiler/src/directive_resolver.ts#L42) function, which essentially picks the first decorator properties in your file.

So in your case only the `my-cmp` will be supported. If you use in your html `my-cmpnt` tag, you will get an error:

> Template parse errors: 'my-cmpnt' is not a known element:

Comment: `If you use in your html my-cmpnt tag, you will get an error that this is not a valid tag` Why?

Comment: There would not be any error. If I have classes for respective components, It'll work fine

Comment: Decorators  are applied right to left. So `annotations` for `MyComponent` will be like `[DecoratorFactory with my-cmpnt, DecoratorFactory with my-cmp]` When angular is resolving metadata `findLast` function(https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.2.0-rc.1/packages/compiler/src/directive_resolver.ts#L42) is used. So only `DecoratorFactory` with `my-cmp` will work

Comment: @Mr_Perfect, _If I have classes for respective components_ - you keep changing the question. That's not a good thing on stackoverflow. In your edited question you have one class only for two decorators

Comment: @yurzui, _Why?_ - your answered your own question I suppose :), because _So only DecoratorFactory with my-cmp will work_