# What happens if we write two decorator functions in single App module?

Tags: angular

I have code like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app1',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Bye {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})

export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `react! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}
```

I don't understand what happens when these two `selectors` are used in the application.  What components gets the data from class and how.

Comment: You should read the docs on [TypeScript decorators](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) to learn how decorators work. Pay close attention to the end of the document where it explains about metadata. This is what Angular uses. It attaches metadata to the class constructor. You could use the same technique to extract the metadata. I haven't tested but my guess would be that the latter (closer to class) one completely overwrites the previous one.

Comment: I tried and the second decorator seems to be skipped.

Comment: Yeah. It is skipping. Buy why? Can you explain the reason why it does that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when there are two classes, one decorator/ one class two decorators in a file in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253962/what-happens-when-there-are-two-classes-one-decorator-one-class-two-decorators)