# Missing BrowserModule Error but Included in App Module

Tags: angular

When I try to serve my angular application I get the following error

> zone.js:642 Unhandled Promise rejection: No ErrorHandler. Is platform
>   module (BrowserModule) included? ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ;
>   Value: Error: No ErrorHandler. Is platform module (BrowserModule)
>   included?

but in my app.module I have

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {BsDropdownModule} from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import {TabsModule} from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';
import {NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES} from './shared/nav-dropdown.directive';

import {ChartsModule} from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
import {SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES} from './shared/sidebar.directive';
import {AsideToggleDirective} from './shared/aside.directive';
import {BreadcrumbsComponent} from './shared/breadcrumb.component';


// Routing Module
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app.routing';

// Firebase
import {AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2';
import {AngularFireAuthModule} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';

// Layouts
import {FullLayoutComponent} from './layouts/full-layout.component';

import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
import {SimpleLayoutComponent} from './layouts/simple-layout.component';
import {AuthService} from './auth/auth.service';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {DragulaModule, DragulaService} from 'ng2-dragula';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

import {AdminGuard} from './admin-guard.service';


@NgModule({
  exports: [
    MatSliderModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
  ]
})

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    ChartsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    HttpModule,

  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FullLayoutComponent,
    SimpleLayoutComponent,
    NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES,
    BreadcrumbsComponent,
    SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES,
    AsideToggleDirective,
  ],
  providers: [{
      provide: LocationStrategy,
      useClass: HashLocationStrategy
    },
    AngularFireDatabase,
    AuthService,
    DragulaService,
    AdminGuard,

],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Would not get this error before when I used Angular 4.1.3 but when I upgraded to Angular 5.2 I get this error in my browser's console. I am not sure if it is because I am missing something in this file, or when I updated something is causing the error.

What is causing this error?

Comment: post whole app.module.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have two `@ngModule` decorator on one class

If you use two decorators on the same class, both will be applied to the class and store metadata on that class in reverse order, so that the first decorator properties stored in the last index. When the compiler resolves metadata it takes the last metadata properties using the findLast function, which essentially picks the first decorator properties in your file.
*In short, only the first decorator is used*.[More here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44253999/5695162)
revise your app module put the `exports` array as described below, this will fix the issue. [Docs](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules)

```
@NgModule({
exports: [
    MatSliderModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    ChartsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    HttpModule,

  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FullLayoutComponent,
    SimpleLayoutComponent,
    NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES,
    BreadcrumbsComponent,
    SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES,
    AsideToggleDirective,
  ],
  providers: [{
      provide: LocationStrategy,
      useClass: HashLocationStrategy
    },
    AngularFireDatabase,
    AuthService,
    DragulaService,
    AdminGuard,

],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```